# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio 2008 Designer to always redraw window when jumping between code and design window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I wasn't sure how to write topic correctly but lemme describe what problem I have. On my old laptop when i was jumping between code and big WinForm GUI it took sometimes a lot of time before i could even do things within designer. Today I've changed my laptop to newer one and it still has some delays when "redrawing/rebuilding" winform gui.

Is there a way to prevent it to do that? I mean nothing in GUI changes so why would it need to redraw the gui again and again :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no it is not possible to stop this behavior.

Comment: Too bad :| Guess I have to hope new computer won't be as bad as last one.

Answer (score 1):

Before leaving the code view and going to the design view, save and do a build (F6). Often enough (but not always) the design view will not be redrawn.